# Validate TypeError when it is undefined in ngOnInit method call

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript

I have an input on my screen that will only display it when the `filter_type` is the same as the description, whenever I load the page for the first time the filter_type has no value and then the input is not shown on the screen, since I only want to show when `filter_type` is same as description.

There is an error occurring because `@ViewChild` does not fill the element on my page ... I need to handle this so no error occurs when filter_type is different from description.

Here is the code I wrote:

**mycomponent.ts:**

```
@ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    // I tried to validate this way but there is an error anyway ...
    if (typeof this.filter.nativeElement !== 'undefined') {
        // The error occurs here
        Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .debounceTime(150)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(() => {
                if (!this.dataSource) {
                    return;
                }
                this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;

            });
    }
}
```

**mycomponent.html:**

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="filter_type === 'description'" floatPlaceholder="never" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
    <input id="search" matInput #filter placeholder="Search">
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I hide and display the input without an error occurring updating `this.dataSource.filter` only when `filter_type` is description to filter the objects in my array?

**Error that occurs at startup:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at eval (eval at mycomponent.ngOnInit (mycomponent.component.ts:19), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at ExtratoComponent.ngOnInit (mycomponent.component.ts:111)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (mycomponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to make use of the [form control features in Angular 2](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You can create a `FormControl` object that can manage watching for changes to the value and subscribe to that object. You wire up the template `<input>` to make use of the `FormControl` object. I put together a [simple Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K0yMJANeT041KEPA5Sac?p=preview) showing this behavior.

**mycomponent.ts:**

Initialize the form control and wire up the code for handling the changes.

```js
searchControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(150)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(() => {
            if (!this.dataSource) {
                return;
            }
            this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;

        });
}
```

**mycomponent.html:**

Wire up the `<input>` to the form control.

```html
<input ... [formControl]="searchControl">
```

Comment: I liked this way, I had not thought about it ... so I choose this as a solution ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The @ViewChild() you are trying to access is within an *ngIf, so it does not always exist.

Use [@ViewChildren()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) instead. It will provide you with an observable of 'current' matching element(s).

Example:

```
@ViewChildren('filter') filter: QueryList<any>
ngOnInit () {
  this.filter.changes.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val)
  })
}
```

Note that when using @ViewChildren(), the object type is `QueryList<>`. So, you have to handle it differently. Refer to the docs for @ViewChildren().

Comment: @LuizRicardoCardoso i've updated it with a simple example. You should be able to adapt it to your use case.

Comment: I did this inside the ngAfterViewInit () method and it worked perfectly ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when ngOnInit is fired, `this.filter` is **undefined** and it therefore does not have a `nativeElement` property.

To get rid of the error, you'd have to replace your `if` with:

```
if (typeof this.filter !== 'undefined') {
   // your logic here
}
```

But this would mean that whenever `this.filter` is undefined, the Observable is not attached, so there might be cases when you have to find another event to attach it (probably making sure it's not attached twice).